# Constructor failed to take input arguments

Tags: python, linux, class, error-handling, constructor

I am new to Python. I had been following online tutorials about python classes but I get a strange error.

I can't figure out what worng have I done.

Below is my code:

```
class StudentData:
  "Contains information of all students"
  studentNumber = 0;
  def _init_(self,name,age,marks):
      self.name = name;
      self.age = age;
      self.marsk = marks;
  def displayStudentNUmber(self):
      print 'Total Number of students = ',studentNumber;
  def displayinfo(self):
      print 'Name of the Student: ',name;
      print 'Age of the Student: '.age;
      print 'Marks of the Student: '.marks;
student1 = StudentData('Ayesha',12,90)
student2 = StudentData('Sarah',13,89)
print "Student number in case of student 1",student1.displayStudentNumber();
print "Information of the Student",student1.dispalyinfo();
print "Student number in case of student 1",student2.displayStudentNumber();
print "Information of the Student",student2.dispalyinfo();
```

and following is the **ERROR** :

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 14, in 
>   student1 = StudentData('Ali',12,90) TypeError: this constructor takes
>   no arguments

Can anybody explain why I get this error.

Sorry for a lame question :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__init__()` is supposed to have two underscores on either side, and so python has treated yours as just a normal function in your class.

Change:

```
def _init_(self,name,age,marks):
```

To

```
def __init__(self,name,age,marks):
```